# Sending APNS notifications through GCM: legally allowed by apple?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

In order to send notifications by GCM, it's required to register your Client SSL Certificate at the GCM services of google.
This certificate is generated by Apple CA and there's policy called `Apple AAI CPS v6.0` that applies to this particular type of Client SSL Certificate.

Apple states explicitly:  `"Subscribers are obligated to: ... Take no action to transfer their Certificate to any third-party unless otherwise authorized by Apple".` In this case, Google is a third-party.

Did Apple authorize Google to be a third-party?
And is there some kind of online publication of the authorization statement?

Answer (score 0):

If UrbanAirship, Parse, Amazon SNS and  many other third party push notification service providers are allowed then Google is also allowed. In all these instances you have to upload the push ssl cert to them in order to allow them to send notifications to the APNS. So bottomline, you should have no problems doing this.

Read section 2.10 and 2.11.2 of http://images.apple.com/certificateauthority/pdf/Apple_AAI_CPS_v6.0.pdf

Comment: I know, but in addition to that, in 2.11.7 subscriber obligations, it states: 
"Take no action to transfer their Certificate to any third-party unless otherwise authorized by Apple.".  
So Google needs to be authorized by Apple to become a 3rd party. If not, Apple might cut off all Google's connections.